# Install an older kernel 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, kernel

I'm lost.  I cannot find the answer I need anywhere.  I updated to 4.4.0-81 and ever since doing so I cannot access many of my installed software.  Nothing happens.  No errors coming up.  I would like to get back to 4.4.0-77 which worked fine.  I made the mistake of purging the functional kernel before testing.  I cannot figure out how to roll-back.

My system was stable as can be with the older Kernel.  How can I go back?

linux-headers-4.4.0-81                                           4.4.0-81.104~14.04.1                                      all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.4.0

ii  linux-headers-4.4.0-81-generic                                   4.4.0-81.104~14.04.1                                      amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP

ii  linux-headers-generic-lts-xenial                                 4.4.0.81.66

Comment: they should be in the repository, install the old ones and remove the new ones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start `synaptic` and search for the kernel id you want.  I could not find 4.4.0-77 so I used 4.4.0-78 for this example.  Select the 4 packages shown for your kernel.

[image]

Install them, then reboot.  Hold left shift to get the grub menu if you don't have it displayed by default.  Select *Advanced Options for Ubuntu* from the grub menu and select the kernel you want.

FYI, in general, it is a good idea to keep at least the last old kernel around, in case stuff like this happens.

Comment: I usually do keep the old Kernel.  Not sure why I didn't this time.  But what you suggested was so simple, I had no Idea I could do that.  Unfortunately I was doing all of that remotely, edited my grub conf file, set it to select the older kernel, and the computer did not come back online after a remote reboot.  It could be because i messed up the grub conf file selection, but since I'm not in front of the computer, I do not know what is on the screen now.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome. If it worked for you, please accept and/or upvote the answer I gave!